# How to show a curve lies in a plane given 3 constant vectors

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, parametrization

How does one show that given 3 non-parallel vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, a curve with parameterisation:
$$\textbf{s}(t)=(x_1t^2+y_1t+c_1,x_2t^2+y_2t+c_2,x_3t^2+y_3t+c_3)$$ lies in a plane? 
Additionally, how do we find the equation of the plane?

I know that any two non-parallel vectors lie on a plane but have no idea when it comes to 3...

Answer (score 2):

Note that $ s(t) = \begin{pmatrix} 
x_1 & y_1 & c_1\\
x_2 & y_2 & c_2\\
x_3 & y_3 & c_3 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} t^{2} \\
t\\
1 \end{pmatrix}$, and the curve $ \begin{pmatrix} t^{2} \\
t\\
1 \ \end{pmatrix} $ lies in a plane, and the image of a plane under a linear transformation is a plane.

Comment: In case it isnt immediately obvious, the plane is the image of the plane $ \{ \begin{pmatrix} x\\
y\\ 1\\ \end{pmatrix} | x,y \in \mathbb{R} \} $ under the aforementioned linear transformation.

Answer (score 2):

$s(t)$ is a plane curve iff $\det(s'(t),s''(t),s'''(t))=0$.

Comment: I think this condition is sufficient but not necessary. Think e.g. about the circle $\mathbf{s}(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, 1)$. Then $\mathbf{s}(t)$, $\mathbf{s}'(t)$ and $\mathbf{s}''(t)$ are not linearly independent.

Comment: You are right. It was a typo. Thanks.